# Typo3 persistence variables in extended tx_scheduler_Task class

Tags: variables, persistence, typo3, protected

I am not sure how to call it other then "persistence". It took me quit a while to figure out why my code was not working on adding an item in my array...

Lets say I have a class with a protected array variable:

```
protected $fields = array(
        'Features', 'Id'
    );
```

I my class i can use this in a method by using: $this->fields

First time all is well.

Now i do change some stuff and i need another field, so I update me $fields to:

```
 protected $fields = array(
            'Features', 'Id', 'Title'
        );
```

Strangely, if I now want to use $this->fields, they are "gone". On var_dump it returns NULL. Only if I change the name, the protected var can be used again. But I do not want to change the name of course.

I did empty all cache and reloaded browser etc, but nothing does work. Anyone an idea?

Update: I should add it is in a scheduler class that extends tx_scheduler_Task.

Comment: is that field persisted in the database? e.g. is there a field in your table called fields? if so the persistence manager will load the field upon reload and empty your predefined values (and will probably change the type to string as there are no array values in the database)

Comment: Are you using an OPCache, which caches php script parts? Check out the install tool, there you can wipe almost all OPCache implementations. In PHP 5.6, the builtin OPCache is enabled by default.

Comment: @konsolenfreddy: No, it is not in the database. If i change the name, it works 'till I add another item in the array. It stops working untill I again change the array name...

Comment: @Merec: no, OPCache is not used.